# ScrollViewer in Windows 8: always show vertical scrollbar

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How always show vertical scrollbar in the scrollviewer?

It disappear in few seconds, but I want to make scroll visible all the time when scrolling is available

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there might be a bug in the control in Windows 8 Consumer Preview, since the following should normally work:

```
<ScrollViewer
    Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}">
```

As a workaround you can modify the template of the ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer
    Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}"
    Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}">
```

... elsewhere in some ResourceDictionary - the modified standard ScrollViewer template with the "NoIndicator" VisualState removed.

```
    <ControlTemplate
        x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplate1"
        TargetType="ScrollViewer">
        <Border
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup
                    x:Name="ScrollingIndicatorStates">
                    <VisualState
                        x:Name="TouchIndicator">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation
                                TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState
                        x:Name="MouseIndicator">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <FadeInThemeAnimation
                                TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition
                        Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition
                        Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollContentPresenter
                    x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                <ScrollBar
                    x:Name="VerticalScrollBar"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                    Margin="1,0,0,0"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                    Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                <ScrollBar
                    x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                    Margin="0,1,0,0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                    Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" />
                <Rectangle
                    x:Name="ScrollBarSeparator"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="1,1,0,0"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBarTrackBrush}"
                    Stroke="{StaticResource ScrollBarTrackBorderBrush}" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: how can you do it for wp8? it gives an error on `FadeOutThemeAnimation`

Comment: I'd try to extract the template of the ScrollViewer and see if there is anything that could be modified in there to get that effect. The templates are not compatible across platforms. Alternatively you can implement your own indicator.

Answer (score 0):

In Blend:
You can make it visible by editing the template of the VerticalScrollBar which is a part of the ScrollViewers template, which is itself a part of the ListBox template.

Set the Visibility of the **VerticalScrollBar to Visible**, set it's **opacity to 100%** then it will be permanently visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have only developed store apps in HTML/CSS/JavaScript and I experienced the same problem there.

I wanted the scroll bars to always show even when moving the cursor away.

I found this solution in CSS:

```
div#overflowableDiv{
  overflow-y: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
```

**See:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx