# UWP: Show Vertical scroll bar of ListView after adding items

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

`ListView` uses an `ObservableCollection`, and items are added when the user takes some action. Then, until mouse moves onto the `ListView`, scroll bar doesn't show, even the thin one. How to make the scroll bar show as soon as items are added?

I tried `ListView.ScrollIntoView()`, but it didn't work. `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` also didn't work.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583575/how-to-always-show-scrollbar) has a solution for similar question, but it is for horizontal scroll bar, and I want a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scroll bar shows, you need to set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode` property at the same time. The built-in scroll bar will show when the `ListView` control is active, so you need to get the focus manually on your `ListView` control after items are added to let the scroll bar shows as soon as items are added. For example:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" …… ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" >
```

Call the `Focus` method after items are added:

```
//Add items
MyListView.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
```

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is not solved, please feel free to contact us.