# How to visible scroll bar in listview UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I added ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" into ListView tab,
but scrollbars like on the right of the picture is not displayed. It only shows up when I move the mouse near the scrollbar.

★How to display it all time? and may I custom this scrollbar?
(Expectation is the picture on the left)

[image: Expectation is the picture on the left]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47583575/3137337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit troublesome to modify from the code. You can set it directly in the Settings.

**Settings> Accessibility> Visual Effects> Always show scrollBars**.

The following content is about how to modify `ScrollViewer` and `ListView` style from the code side.

The default styles of all the controls of UWP are stored in the **Generic.xaml** file. The file location is as follows

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.22621.0\Generic\generic.xaml

Open the Generic.xaml search for `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView`,`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar` and `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer`, copy the style we need to Page.Resource.

Modify the content of `Collapsed` in `VisualStateGroup x:Name="ConsciousStates"` to keep the scrollbar expanded and not collapsed. The full code is [here](https://github.com/SchrdingerCAT123/CodeShar/blob/main/MainPage.xaml).

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarStyle1" TargetType="ScrollBar">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollBar">
                ...
                ...
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ConsciousStates">

        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition From="Expanded" To="Collapsed">

                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbBackgroundColor}" />
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbBackgroundColor}" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1.0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX" To="0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1.0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateY" To="0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalLargeIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalLargeDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalLargeIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalLargeDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualTransition>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />

        <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="HorizontalTrackRect.Stroke" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackStrokePointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="VerticalTrackRect.Stroke" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackStrokePointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="HorizontalTrackRect.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackFillPointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="VerticalTrackRect.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackFillPointerOver}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>

            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbBackgroundColor}" />
                <ColorAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbBackgroundColor}" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1.0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX" To="0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1.0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateY" To="0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalLargeIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalLargeDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalLargeIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalLargeDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandDuration}" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="ExpandedWithoutAnimation">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="HorizontalTrackRect.Stroke" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackStrokePointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="VerticalTrackRect.Stroke" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackStrokePointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="HorizontalTrackRect.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackFillPointerOver}" />
                <Setter Target="VerticalTrackRect.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackFillPointerOver}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
            <!-- The storyboard below cannot be moved to a transition since transitions
                will not be run by the framework when animations are disabled in the system -->

            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbBackgroundColor}" />
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbBackgroundColor}" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1.0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX" To="0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1.0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateY" To="0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalLargeIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalLargeDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalLargeIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalLargeDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="CollapsedWithoutAnimation">
            <!-- The storyboard below cannot be moved to a transition since transitions
                will not be run by the framework when animations are disabled in the system -->

            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbBackgroundColor}" />
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbBackgroundColor}" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1.0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX" To="0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1.0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumbTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateY" To="0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalLargeIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalLargeDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalSmallIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalLargeIncrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalLargeDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalSmallDecrease" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" BeginTime="{ThemeResource ScrollBarExpandBeginTime}" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

    </VisualStateGroup>
```

Comment: Hi Junjie Zhu, "Modify the content of Collapsed in VisualStateGroup x:Name="ConsciousStates" to keep the scrollbar expanded and not collapsed". sorry, I am a newbie  :( , could you tell me what must I do here? I run your code, but scroll bar does not display.

Comment: Hi Junjie Zhu, I take the code of "Expanded" state, and add into "Collapsed" state, and it works!  :)

Comment: Hi Junjie Zhu,  In your code I saw a comment "Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer".  I also want to custom other component such as button, checkbox..., Where can I get that default xaml?

Comment: The default styles of all the controls of UWP are stored in the Generic.xaml file. My file location is as follows **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.22621.0\Generic\generic.xaml.** You can search for the file generic.xaml through the file search tool.